# .rgs file not found in .rc file. Migration from VS2013 to VS2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio

As a beginner in c++ programing, I have a project which was developed in VS 2013.
I have few questions regarding the .rgs file and .rc files

1. Is the .rgs file created by ALT projects only or is it created automatically while compiling the c++ project?
2. Will the old generated VS2013 .rgs file work with VS2019?
3. I tried to specify the old path location but the compiler is throwing error File not found.
4. Can we create .rgs file from .cpp and .h file?

I acknowledge if I am asking silly questions, since I was not able to find the solution kindly help.

.rgs file

[image: 1st .rgs file]

.rgs file

[image: 2nd .rgs file]

.rc file

[image: .rc file]

Comment: You could refer to the document:[ATL Registry Component](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl/atl-registry-component-registrar?view=msvc-170). Make sure D:\\AutoXX.rgs exists

Comment: Yes the file is present, the problem I am facing is the versions doesn't match so I want to know should I create a new ALT project for this to be executed?
I am getting the following error
LNK2038 mismatch detected for '_MSC_VER': value '1800' doesn't match value '1900' in CadmateCOMInterface.obj AutoCountQTO D:\AutoCountQTO\wrk\CommonUtil.lib(CUTriangle2D.obj)